# how to rotate the elements in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list of elements:

```
list = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
```

What is an idiomatic way to move the first element to the end?

```
foo[list]
```

> {"b", "c", "d","a"}

Comment: Check `RotateLeft`